# Unable to fit a character within a given textview height

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview of height `maxHeight`. I am using following function to choose font size of a string to fit in the textview. The function returns fontsize such that the height of the string matches the textview width. The string is a single digit number. However the textview shows only part of the string . What is wrong ?

```
private int determineMaxTextSizeH(String str, float maxHeight) {
    int size = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    do {
        paint.setTextSize(++ size);
        paint.getTextBounds(str, 0, 1, bounds);
    } while (Math.abs(bounds.height()) < maxHeight);

    return --size;
}
```

This is how the string is displayed.

```
LayoutParams params;
params = textview.getLayoutParams();
params.height = maxHeight;
params.width=maxHeight;
textview.setLayoutParams(params);
int textsize=determineMaxTextSizeH("4", maxHeight);
textview.setTextSize(textsize);
textview.setText("4");
```

XML code of the textview is the following.

```
   <TextView 
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
android:background="@drawable/scorecircle"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"

/>
```

This is the outcome. The complete circle is the relevant textview. The circle is a background layer-list XML. I was trying to write "4".

[image]

Comment: what's the circle behind the 4? anyways, you code looks correct, i haven't tried it. are you sure you don't have any padding set to the textView? please post the xml code as well.

Comment: edited to answer the doubts.

Comment: there is no padding set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `paint.setTextSize()` sets the text size in pixels, therefore `determineMaxTextSizeH()` returns the value in pixels too.

But `textview.setTextSize()` sets the text size in SP by default. Try this:

```
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize)
```

### UPD

I found that TextView draws the text with using the font paddings. So I change the  `determineMaxTextSizeH()` code to respecting the font metrics:

```
private int determineMaxTextSizeH(float maxHeight)
{
    int size = 1;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    FontMetrics fm = new FontMetrics();
    do
    {
        paint.setTextSize(++size);
        paint.getFontMetrics(fm);
    } while((Math.abs(fm.top) + Math.abs(fm.bottom)) < maxHeight);

    return --size;
}
```

Setup TextView:

```
textview.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
LayoutParams params = textview.getLayoutParams();
params.height = maxHeight;
params.width= maxHeight;
textview.setLayoutParams(params);
int textsize = determineMaxTextSizeH(maxHeight);
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);
textview.setText("4");
```

XML code for my TextView:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_text"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FFBBBBBB"/>
```

And it's work on my device, but paddings still there.